# problem of syntax in function indirect hlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I did this function in excel, and it works perfectly :

```
=RECHERCHEH(H$3;INDIRECT("'"&parametre!$B$3&"["&parametre!$B$4&"]"&parametre!$B$5&"'!$1:$200");LIGNE();0)
```

But when I try to replace
`$1:$200` per

```
=RECHERCHEH(H$3;INDIRECT("'"&parametre!$B$3&"["&parametre!$B$4&"]"&parametre!$B$5&"'!RECHERCHEV(C5;parametre!$B$7:$C$11;2)");LIGNE();0)
```

it doesn't work.

when I isolate my function rechercheV,  I got it :

```
=RECHERCHEV(C5;parametre!$B$7:$C$11;2)
```

and it returns me :

```
AF:BE
```

So i try to put in my function rechercheV in my "big function" but no way to work for the moment

Can you help me pls ?

Thanks for reading me

Comment: You need to remove the quotes around "'!RECHERCHEV(C5;parametre!$B$7:$C$11;2)"

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried to do this, but it put me error syntax, can you show me formula excact pls ? because I can't remove totally,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes around `RECHERCHEV(C5;parametre!$B$7:$C$11;2)` mean that exactly that text "RECHERCHEV(...." is being interpreted for the formula, not the value that the function would return.

Try this:

```
=RECHERCHEH(H$3;INDIRECT("'"&parametre!$B$3&"["&parametre!$B$4&"]"&parametre!$B$5&"'!"&RECHERCHEV(C5;parametre!$B$7:$C$11;2));LIGNE();0)
```

Comment: thanks it works, but I don't get why it didn't work for me yet, but thanks a lot !!

Comment: When you enclose `"RECHERCHEV(...)"` in quotes, you're not getting `AF:BE` as the result of a function call, but exactly the text that was in the quotes, namely  `"RECHERCHEV(...)"` . It doesn't evaluate the formula, it just uses the text you gave, which of course as part of a cell reference is just nonsense.

Comment: @fred, I noticed in your profile that you have asked a number of questions recently but haven't accepted any answers on them. On SO if an answer works for you, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark. It's the rep that the answerer gets that keeps the site running.